# Add target hours onto the next working day if job is logged after a certain time

Tags: sql, oracle, time

Bit of a specific request / query but hope that I can explain it correctly, and that it makes sense.

- The working day is 8am-5pm Monday-Friday
- Each job has a target response time eg 1 hour, 2 hours, 4 hours
- Some jobs it shows the target response time as outside of the working day eg a 4 hour job logged at 4:15pm will show a target response time of 8:15pm.

What I would like to do (and not even sure if it is possible) is:

If the priority_code is GC04 (1 hour job) and the time logged is after 4pm on a Monday-Fri take whatever time is before 5pm and add the remainder on to the next working day from 8am.
So an example would be 1 hour job logged at 4:15pm on Monday would show a target response time of 8:15am on Tuesday morning. (45 minutes used on Monday and 15 minutes carried over to Tuesday).

If the priority_code is GC05 (2 hour job) and the time logged is after 3pm on a Monday-Fri take whatever time is before 5pm and add the remainder on to the next working day from 8am.
So an example would be 2 hour job logged at 3:15pm on Monday would show a target response time of 8:15am on Tuesday morning. (1 hour 45 minutes used on Monday and 15 minutes carried over to Tuesday).

If the priority_code is GC06 (4 hour job) and the time logged is after 1pm on a Monday-Fri take whatever time is before 5pm and add the remainder on to the next working day from 8am.
So an example would be 4 hour job logged at 1:15pm on Monday would show a target response time of 8:15am on Tuesday morning. (3 hours 45 minutes used on Monday and 15 minutes carried over to Tuesday).

THANK YOU TO ALEX POOLE I'VE NOW GOT IT WORKING 
Coding is below

```
select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, clock_start, 
target_comp_date,
case
   when to_char(target_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
   and floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
   then target_time + 2 + 63/24
           when floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
           then target_time + 15/24
                  else target_time
end as target_time

from (
select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, clock_start, 
TARGET_COMP_DATE,
CASE 
WHEN PRIORITY_CODE IN ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07') 
THEN
clock_start 
+ case priority_code 
when 'GC01' then 1 
when 'GC02' then 2 
when 'GC03' then 0.5
when 'GC04' then 1 
when 'GC05' then 2 
when 'GC06' then 4
when 'GC07' then 24

end
/ 24 

ELSE
TARGET_COMP_DATE END as target_time

from              (
 select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, target_comp_date,
 case
 when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
 and floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
 then trunc(job_entry_date) + 80/24
     when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sat'
      then trunc(job_entry_date) + 56/24
          when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 
 'Sun'
          or floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
          then trunc(job_entry_date) + 32/24
               when floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) < 8
               then trunc(job_entry_date) + 8/24
                    else job_entry_date
  end as clock_start
  from job
                )
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for the minus votes
The formula I think I need is:

if priority = 1 hour and Job_Logged hour > 16 
then add 1 working day and change start time to 8am + (60 - (1700 - job_logged_hour_and_minute)

Just need to figure what that looks like in Oracle SQL

Comment: What happens if something is logged out-of-hours? Or can't that happen? Also, what data type is the `logged_time`?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly convoluted approach, which assumes your `logged_time` column is a timestamp (easy to adapt if it's a date), and that it can't be out-of-hours:

```
select id, priority_code, logged_time,
  logged_time
    +
    -- response time
    (
      interval '1' hour
        * case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end
    )
    +
    -- actual time adjustment
    (
      -- possible time adjustment...
      (
        -- gap between 17:00 and 08:00
        interval '15' hour
        +
        -- weekend days, only if Friday
        (
            interval '2' day
              * case when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
                     then 1 else 0 end
        )
      )
      *
      -- ... but only if target exceeds 17:00
      case when extract
      (
        hour from logged_time
        +
        -- response time
        (
          interval '1' hour
            * case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end
        )
      ) > 16 then 1 else 0 end
    )
    as target_time
from your_table;
```

which with some sample data like yours and just before your cut-offs, both on a Friday and Monday, gives:

```
        ID PRIO LOGGED_TIME           TARGET_TIME          
---------- ---- --------------------- ---------------------
         1 GC06 2019-05-26 12:59:59.0 2019-05-26 16:59:59.0
         2 GC06 2019-05-26 13:15:00.0 2019-05-27 08:15:00.0
         3 GC05 2019-05-26 14:59:59.0 2019-05-26 16:59:59.0
         4 GC05 2019-05-26 15:15:00.0 2019-05-27 08:15:00.0
         5 GC04 2019-05-26 15:59:59.0 2019-05-26 16:59:59.0
         6 GC04 2019-05-26 16:15:00.0 2019-05-27 08:15:00.0
         7 GC06 2019-05-31 12:59:59.0 2019-05-31 16:59:59.0
         8 GC06 2019-05-31 13:15:00.0 2019-06-03 08:15:00.0
         9 GC05 2019-05-31 14:59:59.0 2019-05-31 16:59:59.0
        10 GC05 2019-05-31 15:15:00.0 2019-06-03 08:15:00.0
        11 GC04 2019-05-31 15:59:59.0 2019-05-31 16:59:59.0
        12 GC04 2019-05-31 16:15:00.0 2019-06-03 08:15:00.0
```

You can reduce some of the duplication with a CTE or inline view:

```
select id, priority_code, logged_time,
  raw_target_time
    +
    -- actual time adjustment
    (
      -- possible time adjustment...
      (
        -- gap between 17:00 and 08:00
        interval '15' hour
        +
        -- weekend days, only if Friday
        (
            interval '2' day
              * case when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
                     then 1 else 0 end
        )
      )
      *
      -- ... but only if target exceeds 17:00
      case when extract (hour from raw_target_time) > 16 then 1 else 0 end
    )
    as target_time
from (
  select id, priority_code, logged_time,
    logged_time
    +
    -- response time
    (
      interval '1' hour
        * case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end
    )
    as raw_target_time
  from your_table
);
```

and of course it doesn't need to be laid out like that, I was just trying to make the logic a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks for this - however it is bringing back the following error message when I have amended the field names....

Comment: The entered SQL is not valid.    SQLSTATE = S1000 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source.

Comment: The logged_time is a date-time field, and jobs can be logged at any time of the day using online web-forms, not just between 8am-5pm.

Comment: 'date-time' isn't an Oracle data type; but that error means your column is  DATE rather than a TIMESTAMP, as I said I was assuming. Please edit your question to explain what should happen if a job is logged out of hours - include examples of various scenarios with expect results, preferably in tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

> jobs can be logged at any time of the day using online web-forms, not just between 8am-5pm

This means that if a job is logged out-of-hours you need to treat it as if it was actually logged at the start of the next working day. (Note that I'm following your question in treating all Mon-Fri as working days - there is nothing in your question about public holidays for instance. Dealing with those would probably be a separate question.)

If you want to break it down you can first figure out when the clock starts on a given job, based on whether it was logged inside or outside the workday. There are a few ways to do this but since you have to deal with weekends I've chosen to do this as:

```
select id, priority_code, logged_time,
  case
    when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
      and floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) >= 17
      then trunc(logged_time) + 56/24
    when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sat'
      then trunc(logged_time) + 56/24
    when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sun'
      or floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) >= 17
      then trunc(logged_time) + 32/24
    when floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) < 8
      then trunc(logged_time) + 8/24
    else logged_time
  end as clock_start
from your_table;
```

The `floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24)` gives you the hour that a job was logged, so you can see if that was lower than 8 (i.e. 8am) or greater than or equal to 17 (i.e. 5pm). Jobs logged at or after 17:00 on Friday or any time at weekends have their clock-start time pushed to the following Monday; jobs logged at or after 17:00 on other days are pushed to the following morning. That's using date arithmetic - 8/24 is 8 hours, 32/24 is 1 day and 8 hours, 56/24 is 2 days and 8 hours etc.

You can then put that into an inline view or CTE to simplify further calculations:

```
with cte1 (id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start) as (
...
)
select id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start,
  clock_start
    + case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end
      / 24 as target_time
from cte1;
```

which will give you the basic target time; and then you can adjust *that* using similar logic to my earlier answer about timestamps and working-day-only logging, but this time using more date manipulation with fractional days instead of with intervals:

```
with cte1 (id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start) as (
  select id, priority_code, logged_time,
    case
      when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
        and floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) >= 17
        then trunc(logged_time) + 80/24
      when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sat'
        then trunc(logged_time) + 56/24
      when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sun'
        or floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) >= 17
        then trunc(logged_time) + 32/24
      when floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) < 8
        then trunc(logged_time) + 8/24
      else logged_time
    end as clock_start
  from your_table
),
cte2 (id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start, target_time) as (
  select id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start,
    clock_start
      + case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end
        / 24 as target_time
  from cte1
)
select id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start,
  case
    when to_char(target_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
      and floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
      then target_time + 63/24
    when floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
      then target_time + 15/24
    else target_time
  end as target_time
from cte2;
```

which with some made-up data for the scenarios I've thought about gives, with the days added just for info to make things hopefully slightly clearer:

```
 ID PRIO LOGGED_TIME         CLOCK_START         TARGET_TIME         LOGGED_DAY CLOCK_DAY TARGET_DAY
--- ---- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- --------- ----------
  1 GC06 2019-05-27 12:59:59 2019-05-27 12:59:59 2019-05-27 16:59:59 Mon        Mon       Mon       
  2 GC06 2019-05-27 13:15:00 2019-05-27 13:15:00 2019-05-28 08:15:00 Mon        Mon       Tue       
  3 GC05 2019-05-27 14:59:59 2019-05-27 14:59:59 2019-05-27 16:59:59 Mon        Mon       Mon       
  4 GC05 2019-05-27 15:15:00 2019-05-27 15:15:00 2019-05-28 08:15:00 Mon        Mon       Tue       
  5 GC04 2019-05-27 15:59:59 2019-05-27 15:59:59 2019-05-27 16:59:59 Mon        Mon       Mon       
  6 GC04 2019-05-27 16:15:00 2019-05-27 16:15:00 2019-05-28 08:15:00 Mon        Mon       Tue       
  7 GC04 2019-05-27 16:59:59 2019-05-27 16:59:59 2019-05-28 08:59:59 Mon        Mon       Tue       
  8 GC04 2019-05-27 17:00:00 2019-05-28 08:00:00 2019-05-28 09:00:00 Mon        Tue       Tue       
  9 GC04 2019-05-28 07:59:59 2019-05-28 08:00:00 2019-05-28 09:00:00 Tue        Tue       Tue       
 10 GC04 2019-05-28 08:00:00 2019-05-28 08:00:00 2019-05-28 09:00:00 Tue        Tue       Tue       
 11 GC06 2019-05-31 12:59:59 2019-05-31 12:59:59 2019-05-31 16:59:59 Fri        Fri       Fri       
 12 GC06 2019-05-31 13:15:00 2019-05-31 13:15:00 2019-06-03 08:15:00 Fri        Fri       Mon       
 13 GC05 2019-05-31 14:59:59 2019-05-31 14:59:59 2019-05-31 16:59:59 Fri        Fri       Fri       
 14 GC05 2019-05-31 15:15:00 2019-05-31 15:15:00 2019-06-03 08:15:00 Fri        Fri       Mon       
 15 GC04 2019-05-31 15:59:59 2019-05-31 15:59:59 2019-05-31 16:59:59 Fri        Fri       Fri       
 16 GC04 2019-05-31 16:15:00 2019-05-31 16:15:00 2019-06-03 08:15:00 Fri        Fri       Mon       
 17 GC04 2019-05-31 16:59:59 2019-05-31 16:59:59 2019-06-03 08:59:59 Fri        Fri       Mon       
 18 GC04 2019-05-31 17:00:00 2019-06-03 08:00:00 2019-06-03 09:00:00 Fri        Mon       Mon       
 19 GC04 2019-06-01 12:00:00 2019-06-03 08:00:00 2019-06-03 09:00:00 Sat        Mon       Mon       
 20 GC04 2019-06-02 12:00:00 2019-06-03 08:00:00 2019-06-03 09:00:00 Sun        Mon       Mon       
 21 GC04 2019-06-03 07:59:59 2019-06-03 08:00:00 2019-06-03 09:00:00 Mon        Mon       Mon       
 22 GC04 2019-06-03 08:00:00 2019-06-03 08:00:00 2019-06-03 09:00:00 Mon        Mon       Mon
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5f3f34497eff38bf20783041e34a2303)

---

Note that the CTE construct is providing aliases for the column expression from the `with (...)` clause, and that those do not have table aliases - as those aliases are unrelated to the tables inside the CTE. So it's `with cte1 (id, priority_code, ...` and *not* `with cte1 (your_table.id, your_table.priority_code, ...`.

Also note that the semicolon at the end is a statement separator, required or optional (or configurable) in some clients, but invalid in others - it can cause ORA-00933 or ORA-00911 errors, and possibly others, in dynamic SQL, JDBC etc.; so ODBC probably also doesn't expect to see that final semicolon character.

If ODBC (or your version) doesn't allow CTEs - suggested by the 'not a SELECT statement' error you mentioned in a comment - then you can use inline views instead:

```
select id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start,
  case
    when to_char(target_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
      and floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
      then target_time + 2 + 63/24
    when floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
      then target_time + 15/24
    else target_time
  end as target_time
from (
  select id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start,
    clock_start
      + case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end
        / 24 as target_time
  from (
    select id, priority_code, logged_time,
      case
        when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
          and floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) >= 17
          then trunc(logged_time) + 80/24
        when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sat'
          then trunc(logged_time) + 56/24
        when to_char(logged_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sun'
          or floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) >= 17
          then trunc(logged_time) + 32/24
        when floor((logged_time - trunc(logged_time)) * 24) < 8
          then trunc(logged_time) + 8/24
        else logged_time
      end as clock_start
    from your_table
  )
);
```

Added to [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8132961e589ccb8ab278b125bb8452ef).

---

It's a little unclear but to keep a pre-calculated `target_comp_date` for other priorities you could change the first inline view (based on cte2) to have nested case expressions:

```
...
from (
  select id, priority_code, logged_time, clock_start,
    case when priority_code in ('GC04', 'GC05', 'GC06') then
      -- for these, calculate the target time based on clock-start as before
      clock_start
        + case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end
          / 24
    else
      -- for any other priority use the original pre-calculated time
      target_comp_date
    end as target_time
  from (
    select id, priority_code, logged_time, target_comp_date,
...
```

The innermost inline view needs to include that extra column in its select list, so it's visible to that nested case expression.

> The system will show the target_comp_date incorrect as 12am

You should probably be fixing that existing code then, rather than trying to fudge the result it gives you.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.
I can get the first bit to code to work from your answer where it shows when the clock starts on any given job, however when I try and add the coding below
"with fractional days instead of with intervals:" and change it for the fields in the database I get the following error message

"SQLSTATE = S1000  [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-02000: missing ) keyword

I'll try and post my coding up here but it says I've run out of characters and I'm not sure it shows coding correct (I'm fairly new so probably missing something)

Comment: Comments are not meant for code, which is unreadable. I think you've misunderstood how CTEs work - the aliases in the `with(...) as` part should *not* have table prefixes.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole.  I've posted the SQL I've got now after making amendments but keep getting an error message saying the command not properly ended.  Would be very grateful if you could have a look and advise as I'm really lost on this

Comment: @RobMorris - the ORA-00933 was probably because of the trailing semicolon (I added a note about that). I'm not sure about the 'not a SELECT statement` - maybe ODBC, or your version of it, doesn't understand CTEs? You can convert those to inline views instead.

Comment: I think the SQL statement in the program always has to start with SELECT, and by having it start with WITH is what's causing the error.

I'm sorry to keep asking for help and sounding stupid on this (i've been using this version of SQL for about 3 months now and really struggling) but how do I go about converting CTE's into inline views for this code?

Comment: Thank you - that has worked but I've one final query / question.
If the priority code isn't (GC04/05/06) then it needs to bring through the original target completion date on the job without any amendments (this field is called target_comp_date)

I thought it would just be a case of amending the + case priority_code when 'GC04' then 1 when 'GC05' then 2 when 'GC06' then 4 end  / 24 as target_time line to  ...when 'GC06' then 4 else target_comp_date end / 24 as target_time          however this brings back an error saying that target_comp_date is an invalid identifier

Comment: I don't know where `target_comp_date ` is coming from, but if that's a date you can't stick it in a clause that's expecting numbers anyway. You'll need to decide whether the clock-start time changes too, and thus where in the query you need to handle other priorities differently. For instance, you might need the innermost case expression to have a first clause that returns the original logged_time for other priorities. I'm confused though, do all rows already have that `target_comp_date` which already has most of this logic baked in?

Comment: All jobs have a target completion time, which is based on the priority of the job, and when the job was logged.  A job logged at 10am with a priority of 1 hour will have a target_comp_date of 11am.  The issue arises when a job is logged at 11pm with a priority of 1 hour.  The system will show the target_comp_date incorrect as 12am, instead of 9am the following day.

The following priorities can be allocated to jobs a) 1 hour b) 2 hours c) 4 hours d) 1 working day e) 2 working days f) 5 working days.

Comment: D, E and F don't have any issue with the target_comp_date as if they are logged at 11pm the system automatically starts them as 8am,  it's A, B and C where the issue arises as the system doesn't automatically push them over to 8am the next day.

Comment: OK, so if I'm following that then like I said, add an initial clause to the innermost case so it doesn't adjust the clock-start for the other priorities, and the middle one to add multiples of 24 for D/E/F. Or if you don't want to recalculate that, change the middle one to have a nested case expression, that takes the pre-calculate `target_comp_date` for those other priorities, and the clock_start + x only for A/B/C.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this Alex and your patience - it's now working! 
I've put the code I've got to get it working in the original message - if you want to put that as an answer I'd be happy to flag it as such!

Comment: You shouldn't post the solution as part of the question (this site stresses being about Q&A, for the benefit of future visitors and not just you; and not being a forum). I don't really see enough difference in what you posted to justify a(nother) separate answer - you've added codes what weren't in the original question and changed table/column names, but it's essentially what is in this answer, so I don't think there's even any benefit in adding your modified code to this. It's already much too long...